# How to store JSON data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to implement dependent dropdowns using JavaScript. I have three dropdowns country, state and city and the data for the dropdowns is to be accessed from the below JSON data, I want to store the data in such a way that all countries should be stored in country array, based on the country, states should be stored in state array and based on states, city should be stored in city array. I have tried using for loop but I am able to access only the innermost key value pair i.e city.

```
var country=     {
        "Countries": [{
            "Country": "Country1",
            "states": [{
                "state": "state1",
                "city": ["city1", "city2"]
            }, {
                "state": "state2",
                "city": ["city1", "city2"]
            }]
        }, {
            "Country": "Country2",
            "states": [{
                "state": "state3",
                "city": ["city1", "city2"]
            }, {
                "state": "state4",
                "city": ["city1", "city2"]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json data to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409909/convert-json-data-to-array)

Comment: Please show what code you tried, and what the output was which was unexpected. It's also unclear if the code you're showing is the input or the desired output. You should also note that there is no JSON in your question, because JSON refers to strings. These are objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I've tried to use a indexing-like approach to solve the problem. From the given object I have created 3 arrays (for country, state & city) where I'm storing the names as well as reference to other arrays. Such that:

*Country Array*

```
{
  country_id: index of country,
  country: name of country
}
```

*State Array*

```
{
  state_id: index of state,
  state: name of state,
  country_id: reference to country array
}
```

*City Array*

```
{
  city_id: index of city,
  city: name of city,
  state_id: reference to state array
}
```

Using the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function I am retrieving the states (based on country ID) and cities (based on state ID). See below:

**Example Code**

```
/**
 * Example
 * @type {Object}
 */
var country = {
    "Countries": [{
        "Country": "Country1",
        "states": [{
            "state": "state11",
            "city": ["city111", "city112"]
        }, {
            "state": "state12",
            "city": ["city121", "city122"]
        }]
    }, {
        "Country": "Country2",
        "states": [{
            "state": "state23",
            "city": ["city231", "city232"]
        }, {
            "state": "state24",
            "city": ["city241", "city242"]
        }]
    }]
};

/**
 * Default starting ID for state list
 * @type {Number}
 */
var state_id = 0;

/**
 * Default starting ID for city list
 * @type {Number}
 */
var city_id = 0;

/**
 * Array of country names
 * @type {Array}
 */
var country_array = [];

/**
 * Array of states (along with ID of country they belong to)
 * @type {Array}
 */
var state_array = [];

/**
 * Array of cities (along with ID of state they belong to)
 * @type {Array}
 */
var city_array = [];

/////////////////
// THE PROCESS //
/////////////////
country.Countries
    .forEach(function(each_country, country_index) {

        country_array
            .push({
                country_id: country_index,
                country: each_country.Country
            });

        each_country.states
            .forEach(function(each_state) {

                state_array
                    .push({
                        state_id: state_id,
                        state: each_state.state,
                        country_id: country_index
                    });

                each_state.city
                    .forEach(function(each_city) {

                        city_array
                            .push({
                                city_id: city_id,
                                city: each_city,
                                state_id: state_id
                            });

                        city_id = city_array.length; // Calculating the next city_id
                    });

                state_id = state_array.length; // Calculating the next state_id
            });
    });

/**
 * Returns array of countries
 * @return {[Object]} Array of countries
 */
var getCountryList = function() {
    return country_array;
};

/**
 * Returns array of states belonging to a country
 * @param  {Number}   country_id The index of the country in the country array
 * @return {[Object]}            Array of states
 */
var getStateList = function(country_id) {
    return state_array
        .filter(function(each) {
            return each.country_id === country_id;
        });
};

/**
 * Returns array of cities belonging to a state
 * @param  {Number}   state_id The index of the state in the state array
 * @return {[Object]}          Array of cities
 */
var getCityList = function(state_id) {
    return city_array
        .filter(function(each) {
            return each.state_id === state_id;
        });
};

// Retrieve the country list
getCountryList();

// Retrieve the state list of country with ID 0
getStateList(0);

// Retrieve the state list of country with ID 1
getStateList(1);

// Retrieve the city list of state with ID 0
getCityList(0);

// Retrieve the city list of state with ID 1
getCityList(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to return one object with key/value pairs where for example key is city or state and value is array of all cities.

```js
var country = {
  "Countries": [{
    "Country": "Country1",
    "states": [{
      "state": "state1",
      "city": ["city1", "city2"]
    }, {
      "state": "state2",
      "city": ["city1", "city2"]
    }]
  }, {
    "Country": "Country2",
    "states": [{
      "state": "state3",
      "city": ["city1", "city2"]
    }, {
      "state": "state4",
      "city": ["city1", "city2"]
    }]
  }]
}

var result = country.Countries.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.country = (r.country || []).concat(e.Country);
  e.states.forEach(function(a) {
    r.state = (r.state || []).concat(a.state);
    r.city = (r.city || []).concat(a.city);
  })
  return r;
}, {})


console.log(result)
```